# String Permutation method that returns String[]

Tags: java

I have asked this question before and for some reaseon people say its repeated!
the soultions I found are all void
I want the methode to be like this:

```
public String[] permutations(String str){//code}
```

for example if I have a string "abc" the output should be: 
a, b, c, ab, ac, ba, bc, ca, cb, abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba
I tried to convert the methods I found from void to String[] but I couldn't do it. it always have errors

Comment: Post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Show your code and post the errors that you are getting.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. I don't know what sort you're applying (if any), so I'm just not doing one.

```
public String[] permutations(String str) {
    if (str.length() == 0) {
        return new String[0];
    } else if (str.length() == 1) {
        String[] s = new String[1];
        s[0] = str;
        return s;
    }
    Set<String> permutations = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        String part = str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i + 1);
        String[] rem = permutations(part);
        for (String s : rem) {
            permutations.add(s);
            for (int j = 0; j <= s.length(); j++) {
                String t = s.substring(0, j) + c + s.substring(j);
                permutations.add(t);
            }
        }
    }
    return permutations.toArray(new String[permutations.size()]);
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for posting
the solution is better than mine but it skips some permutations. in the case of the "abc" input, it skips "bca" and "cba"

Comment: Edited. Sorry about that, should be accurate now. I just changed < s.length() to <= and did the splicing in of c for every string in rem.